# Validation of Input Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i created a simple search input form for a Rails application, but i noticed that when i dont input anything it returns a result of all my users, but i dont want it to work when no value is placed

My form

```
<h6>Search for Friends</h6>
  <form action ="users/search" method="post">
    <input name = "key" type="input" />
    <input value="Search" type="submit"/>
  </form>
```

Controller method

```
def search
  @users = User.find(:all,:order => 'username', :conditions => ["username LIKE ?", "%#{params[:key]}%"])
end
```

Comment: Which version of rails you have used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the new Arel writing or check if the key was assigned.

```
def search 
  @users = User.where(["username LIKE ?", "%#{params[:key]}%"]).order('username')
end
```

or

```
def search 
  if params[:key].blank?
    @users = []
  else
    @users = User.where(["username LIKE ?", "%#{params[:key]}%"]).order('username')
  end
end
```

Comment: what i want is an sql statement that will not return a result if not letter is input, right now my sql statement returns all values when no value is present and the submiit button is pressed

Comment: from your code i need a place to view it, but how do i write that based on the search method you provided

Comment: try put these line to your search method instead your search query `@users = User.where(["username LIKE ?", "%#{params[:key]}%"]).order('username')`

Comment: i tried the last search method and it still returned all values when no input was made

Comment: thanks the second search method did the trick, thanks bro, i really do appreciate